Installing kernel from another device
I installed Samsung Galaxy S9 firmware (Android 8.0) on a Samsung Galaxy Note9 because they have almost the same specifications, but the problem is that some drivers don't work correctly (fingerprint, camera, audio).
Can I install the Note9 kernel on a Galaxy S9 firmware for the drivers to work correctly?

Different chips need different drivers. If you have a kernel from a different device you have a different set of drivers, therefore it is not unexpected that some components don't work.

You're quite lucky that the Note 9 is working as well as it is. Flashing a ROM for a different device presents a significant risk of bricking it irrecoverably.
Trying to substitute a different kernel into an existing ROM, without a complete understanding of what you're doing, only makes sense if you're happy to sacrifice the device. A complete understanding of what's involved would require having and understanding the full source code of both devices' ROMs, and a detailed knowledge of the hardware. This information is not found in easy-to-digest form on the Internet.

Samsung's Android team(s) could tell you what's involved, but won't answer such questions unless you're part of the company.

The LineageOS source for both devices is available, and you could study that, but it's a big job. Unless you seriously want to take up producing custom Android ROMs, you may find it an excessive amount of work.



I don't actually want to create custom roms, I just want to enjoy my Note9 with Samsung Experience (Samsung's UI skin for Android 7-8, replaced by OneUi) instead of OneUi ...

Unfortunately, that is a custom ROM. It's not one Samsung provides.

I dont actually want to create custom roms, i just want to enjoy my Note9 with Samsung experience instead of OneUi, anyways thanks for help

@sans400: See amended answer.

Yeah i know, i flashed stock S9 firmware just to see if it works, i dont actually want to upload my custom roms somewhere

Btw, Samsung Experience is the name of the software overlay for stock Samsung in Android 7-8. It's succeeded with One UI. Both are indeed stock Samsung (and yes, it's confusing).
